# What does "import" mean for the relation between a proposition and a theorem?

Tags: mathematical-statistics

On p.171 in Bickel and Doksum's Mathematical Statistics 2006,
does "The main practical **import** of minimax theorems is, in fact, contained in a converse and its extension that we now give͝" mean that Proposition 3.3.1 is implied by Theorem 3.3.1?

The proof of Proposition 3.3.1 doesn't rely on Theorem 3.3.1. The condition in Proposition 3.3.1 is also more general than Theorem 3.3.1. So I doubt "import" means "implication".

Thanks.

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: "Bickle" corrected to "Bickel". Giving full bibliographic details of the book would do no harm.

Answer (score 7):

It's a standard English usage of the noun 'import'.

It means something close to "importance" or "significance". There's a closely related sense of the word -- 'underlying meaning'--  which may apply or partly apply in the above context.

e.g. See [this](https://www.google.com/search?q=import+definition) (the second meaning under noun), and [this](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/import) (also the second meaning under 'noun'). See also meanings 10. and 11. [here](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/import) or meanings 3. and 4. [here](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/import), and also see [here](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/import#Noun).

There's no special meaning in relation to connection between a proposition and a theorem - it's not a mathematical term (at least not in this context - perhaps there's some particular meaning in some other context).